# Convert Alpine component to React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, alpine.js

I'm trying to convert an Alpine component in React (Select with Custom Avatar which is the first one) → https://tailwindui.com/components/application-ui/forms/select-menus

To copy Alpine source, you can open up Source tab & copy element from there or I'll paste it below (kept only 3 `li` elements which is repetitive code):

```html
<div class="w-full max-w-xs mx-auto">
  <!--
  Custom select controls like this require a considerable amount of JS to implement from scratch. We're planning
  to build some low-level libraries to make this easier with popular frameworks like React, Vue, and even Alpine.js
  in the near future, but in the mean time we recommend these reference guides when building your implementation:

  https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#Listbox
  https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/listbox/listbox-collapsible.html
-->
  <div
    x-data="Components.customSelect({ open: true, value: 3, selected: 3 })"
    x-init="init()"
  >
    <label id="listbox-label" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
      Assigned to
    </label>
    <div class="mt-1 relative">
      <button
        type="button"
        x-ref="button"
        @keydown.arrow-up.stop.prevent="onButtonClick()"
        @keydown.arrow-down.stop.prevent="onButtonClick()"
        @click="onButtonClick()"
        aria-haspopup="listbox"
        :aria-expanded="open"
        aria-expanded="true"
        aria-labelledby="listbox-label"
        class="relative w-full bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm pl-3 pr-10 py-2 text-left cursor-default focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
      >
        <span class="flex items-center">
          <img
            :src='["https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1491528323818-fdd1faba62cc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=2&amp;w=256&amp;h=256&amp;q=80","https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550525811-e5869dd03032?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=2&amp;w=256&amp;h=256&amp;q=80","https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500648767791-00dcc994a43e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=2.25&amp;w=256&amp;h=256&amp;q=80","https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=2&amp;w=256&amp;h=256&amp;q=80","https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=2&amp;w=256&amp;h=256&amp;q=80","https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1487412720507-e7ab37603c6f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=2&amp;w=256&amp;h=256&amp;q=80","https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1568409938619-12e139227838?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=2&amp;w=256&amp;h=256&amp;q=80","https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531427186611-ecfd6d936c79?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=2&amp;w=256&amp;h=256&amp;q=80","https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584486520270-19eca1efcce5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=2&amp;w=256&amp;h=256&amp;q=80","https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1561505457-3bcad021f8ee?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=2&amp;w=256&amp;h=256&amp;q=80"][value]'
            src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=2&amp;w=256&amp;h=256&amp;q=80"
            alt=""
            class="flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6 rounded-full"
          />
          <span
            x-text='["Wade Cooper","Arlene Mccoy","Devon Webb"][value]'
            class="ml-3 block truncate"
            >Tom Cook</span
          >
        </span>
        <span
          class="ml-3 absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2 pointer-events-none"
        >
          <svg
            class="h-5 w-5 text-gray-400"
            x-description="Heroicon name: selector"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 20 20"
            fill="currentColor"
            aria-hidden="true"
          >
            <path
              fill-rule="evenodd"
              d="M10 3a1 1 0 01.707.293l3 3a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 5.414 7.707 7.707a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414l3-3A1 1 0 0110 3zm-3.707 9.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 14.586l2.293-2.293a1 1 0 011.414 1.414l-3 3a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-3-3a1 1 0 010-1.414z"
              clip-rule="evenodd"
            ></path>
          </svg>
        </span>
      </button>

      <div
        x-show="open"
        @click.away="open = false"
        x-description="Select popover, show/hide based on select state."
        x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-100"
        x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100"
        x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0"
        class="absolute mt-1 w-full rounded-md bg-white shadow-lg"
      >
        <ul
          @keydown.enter.stop.prevent="onOptionSelect()"
          @keydown.space.stop.prevent="onOptionSelect()"
          @keydown.escape="onEscape()"
          @keydown.arrow-up.prevent="onArrowUp()"
          @keydown.arrow-down.prevent="onArrowDown()"
          x-ref="listbox"
          tabindex="-1"
          role="listbox"
          aria-labelledby="listbox-label"
          :aria-activedescendant="activeDescendant"
          class="max-h-56 rounded-md py-1 text-base ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 overflow-auto focus:outline-none sm:text-sm"
          x-max="1"
          aria-activedescendant=""
        >
          <li
            x-description="Select option, manage highlight styles based on mouseenter/mouseleave and keyboard navigation."
            x-state:on="Highlighted"
            x-state:off="Not Highlighted"
            id="listbox-item-0"
            role="option"
            @click="choose(0)"
            @mouseenter="selected = 0"
            @mouseleave="selected = null"
            :class="{ 'text-white bg-indigo-600': selected === 0, 'text-gray-900': !(selected === 0) }"
            class="cursor-default select-none relative py-2 pl-3 pr-9 text-gray-900"
          >
            <div class="flex items-center">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1491528323818-fdd1faba62cc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=2&amp;w=256&amp;h=256&amp;q=80"
                alt=""
                class="flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6 rounded-full"
              />
              <span
                x-state:on="Selected"
                x-state:off="Not Selected"
                :class="{ 'font-semibold': value === 0, 'font-normal': !(value === 0) }"
                class="ml-3 block font-normal truncate"
              >
                Wade Cooper
              </span>
            </div>

            <span
              x-description="Checkmark, only display for selected option."
              x-state:on="Highlighted"
              x-state:off="Not Highlighted"
              x-show="value === 0"
              :class="{ 'text-white': selected === 0, 'text-indigo-600': !(selected === 0) }"
              class="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-4 text-indigo-600"
              style="display: none"
            >
              <svg
                class="h-5 w-5"
                x-description="Heroicon name: check"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                fill="currentColor"
                aria-hidden="true"
              >
                <path
                  fill-rule="evenodd"
                  d="M16.707 5.293a1 1 0 010 1.414l-8 8a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 011.414-1.414L8 12.586l7.293-7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0z"
                  clip-rule="evenodd"
                ></path>
              </svg>
            </span>
          </li>

          <li
            x-description="Select option, manage highlight styles based on mouseenter/mouseleave and keyboard navigation."
            x-state:on="Highlighted"
            x-state:off="Not Highlighted"
            id="listbox-item-1"
            role="option"
            @click="choose(1)"
            @mouseenter="selected = 1"
            @mouseleave="selected = null"
            :class="{ 'text-white bg-indigo-600': selected === 1, 'text-gray-900': !(selected === 1) }"
            class="text-gray-900 cursor-default select-none relative py-2 pl-3 pr-9"
          >
            <div class="flex items-center">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550525811-e5869dd03032?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=2&amp;w=256&amp;h=256&amp;q=80"
                alt=""
                class="flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6 rounded-full"
              />
              <span
                x-state:on="Selected"
                x-state:off="Not Selected"
                :class="{ 'font-semibold': value === 1, 'font-normal': !(value === 1) }"
                class="ml-3 block font-normal truncate"
              >
                Arlene Mccoy
              </span>
            </div>

            <span
              x-description="Checkmark, only display for selected option."
              x-state:on="Highlighted"
              x-state:off="Not Highlighted"
              x-show="value === 1"
              :class="{ 'text-white': selected === 1, 'text-indigo-600': !(selected === 1) }"
              class="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-4 text-indigo-600"
              style="display: none"
            >
              <svg
                class="h-5 w-5"
                x-description="Heroicon name: check"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                fill="currentColor"
                aria-hidden="true"
              >
                <path
                  fill-rule="evenodd"
                  d="M16.707 5.293a1 1 0 010 1.414l-8 8a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 011.414-1.414L8 12.586l7.293-7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0z"
                  clip-rule="evenodd"
                ></path>
              </svg>
            </span>
          </li>

          <li
            x-description="Select option, manage highlight styles based on mouseenter/mouseleave and keyboard navigation."
            x-state:on="Highlighted"
            x-state:off="Not Highlighted"
            id="listbox-item-2"
            role="option"
            @click="choose(2)"
            @mouseenter="selected = 2"
            @mouseleave="selected = null"
            :class="{ 'text-white bg-indigo-600': selected === 2, 'text-gray-900': !(selected === 2) }"
            class="text-gray-900 cursor-default select-none relative py-2 pl-3 pr-9"
          >
            <div class="flex items-center">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500648767791-00dcc994a43e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=facearea&amp;facepad=2.25&amp;w=256&amp;h=256&amp;q=80"
                alt=""
                class="flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6 rounded-full"
              />
              <span
                x-state:on="Selected"
                x-state:off="Not Selected"
                :class="{ 'font-semibold': value === 2, 'font-normal': !(value === 2) }"
                class="ml-3 block font-normal truncate"
              >
                Devon Webb
              </span>
            </div>

            <span
              x-description="Checkmark, only display for selected option."
              x-state:on="Highlighted"
              x-state:off="Not Highlighted"
              x-show="value === 2"
              :class="{ 'text-white': selected === 2, 'text-indigo-600': !(selected === 2) }"
              class="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-4 text-indigo-600"
              style="display: none"
            >
              <svg
                class="h-5 w-5"
                x-description="Heroicon name: check"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                fill="currentColor"
                aria-hidden="true"
              >
                <path
                  fill-rule="evenodd"
                  d="M16.707 5.293a1 1 0 010 1.414l-8 8a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 011.414-1.414L8 12.586l7.293-7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0z"
                  clip-rule="evenodd"
                ></path>
              </svg>
            </span>
          </li>

          <!-- More options... -->
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I understand most of the stuff but I don't understand `@click=choose(0)` & also `x-state:on="Selected" x-state:off="Not Selected"` like where is the `Selected` & `Not Selected` used.

I just want to convert this component into React but some things I am not understanding. Would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with [Listbox](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/headlessui/blob/develop/packages/%40headlessui-react/README.md#listbox-select) component from [@headlessui/react](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/headlessui) to achieve [the same result](https://codesandbox.io/s/listbox-headlessui-react-tailwind-mobx-p1j6r):

## SelectWithAvatar.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Listbox, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
import clsx from 'clsx'

import { Selector, Check } from '@/components/icons/index'

type Option = {
    id: string
    name: string
    img: string
}

interface IProps {
    label?: string
    value: Option
    onChange: (name: string) => void
    options: Array<Option>
}

export const SelectWithAvatar = ({ label, options, value, onChange }: IProps) => {
    return (
        <Listbox
            value={value}
            onChange={(value: Option) => {
                onChange(value.name)
            }}
        >
            {({ open }) => (
                <>
                    <Listbox.Label className="mb-1 text-sm font-medium text-blue-gray-500">
                        {label}
                    </Listbox.Label>

                    <div className="relative mt-1">
                        <Listbox.Button className="relative w-full py-2 pl-3 pr-10 text-left bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm cursor-default focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm">
                            <span className="flex items-center">
                                <img
                                    src={value.img}
                                    alt={value.name}
                                    className="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6 rounded-full"
                                />
                                <span className="block ml-3 truncate">{value.name}</span>
                            </span>
                            <span className="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2 ml-3 pointer-events-none">
                                <Selector />
                            </span>
                        </Listbox.Button>

                        <div className="absolute z-10 w-full mt-1 bg-white rounded-md shadow-lg">
                            <Transition
                                show={open}
                                leave="transition duration-100 ease-in"
                                leaveFrom="transform opacity-100"
                                leaveTo="transform opacity-0"
                            >
                                <Listbox.Options
                                    static
                                    className="py-1 overflow-auto text-base rounded-md max-h-56 ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none sm:text-sm"
                                >
                                    {options.map((option) => {
                                        return (
                                            <Listbox.Option as={React.Fragment} key={option.id} value={option}>
                                                {({ active, selected }) => {
                                                    return (
                                                        <li
                                                            className={clsx(
                                                                'relative py-2 pl-3 cursor-default select-none pr-9',
                                                                {
                                                                    'text-white bg-indigo-600': active,
                                                                    'text-gray-900': !active,
                                                                }
                                                            )}
                                                        >
                                                            <div className="flex items-center">
                                                                <img
                                                                    src={option.img}
                                                                    alt={option.name}
                                                                    className="flex-shrink-0 w-6 h-6 rounded-full"
                                                                />
                                                                <span
                                                                    className={clsx('ml-3 block truncate', {
                                                                        'font-semibold': selected,
                                                                        'font-normal': !selected,
                                                                    })}
                                                                >
                                                                    {option.name}
                                                                </span>
                                                            </div>
                                                            {selected && (
                                                                <span
                                                                    className={clsx(
                                                                        'absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-4',
                                                                        {
                                                                            'text-white': active,
                                                                            'text-indigo-600': !active,
                                                                        }
                                                                    )}
                                                                >
                                                                    <Check />
                                                                </span>
                                                            )}
                                                        </li>
                                                    )
                                                }}
                                            </Listbox.Option>
                                        )
                                    })}
                                </Listbox.Options>
                            </Transition>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </>
            )}
        </Listbox>
    )
}
```

## components/icons/index

```
import React from 'react'

export const Selector = () => (
    <svg
        className="w-5 h-5 text-indigo-600"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        viewBox="0 0 20 20"
        fill="currentColor"
        aria-hidden="true"
    >
        <path
            fillRule="evenodd"
            d="M10 3a1 1 0 01.707.293l3 3a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 5.414 7.707 7.707a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414l3-3A1 1 0 0110 3zm-3.707 9.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 14.586l2.293-2.293a1 1 0 011.414 1.414l-3 3a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-3-3a1 1 0 010-1.414z"
            clipRule="evenodd"
        />
    </svg>
)

export const Check = () => (
    <svg
        className="w-5 h-5"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        viewBox="0 0 20 20"
        fill="currentColor"
        aria-hidden="true"
    >
        <path
            fillRule="evenodd"
            d="M16.707 5.293a1 1 0 010 1.414l-8 8a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 011.414-1.414L8 12.586l7.293-7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0z"
            clipRule="evenodd"
        />
    </svg>
)
```